# Angular js ng-include ng-click bug

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-include

i use angular js and have problem with http://apparently.me.uk/angularjs-view-specific-sidebars/

when i replace block, in replace block angular ignore ng-click [simple example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/3OPhzVuUqHS7VOGRPZuF) (click on text with alert word)

script code:

```
var test = angular.module('test', ['sheikcontrolls']);

var sheikContolls = angular.module("sheikcontrolls",[]);

sheikContolls.controller('BaseController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.name="Alex";

  $scope.getName = function(){
    return $scope.name;
  };
  $scope.alertName = function(){
    alert($scope.name);
  };
});


//SideBar here
var blocks = {};

test.directive('customOnChange', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var onChangeFunc = scope.$eval(attrs.customOnChange);
            element.bind('change', onChangeFunc);
        }
    };
});

test.directive(
    'blockInsertion',
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                var key = iAttrs.blockInsertion;
                blocks[key] = iElement;

                // Assume that block-insertion directives won't get
                // removed after they're inserted. A more robust
                // implementation would clean these up on $destroy.
            }
        };
    }
);
test.directive(
    'blockReplacement',
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                var key = iAttrs.blockReplacement;

                // Prepare to move our element to its corresponding
                // block insertion point.
                iElement.remove();

                if (! blocks[key]) {
                    // No matching block insertion, so just hide.
                    return;
                }

                blocks[key].replaceWith(iElement);

                scope.$on(
                    '$destroy',
                    function () {
                        // Restore the insertion element.
                        iElement.replaceWith(blocks[key]);
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: problem is in `blockReplacement`  when you use `replaceWith` it isn't a compiled element. I don't understand what that directive is for but you should be able to get click back using `$compile`

Comment: Don't quite understand what I should do with $compile. can you describe in more detail ?

Comment: what is the idea behind that directive?

Comment: you can read on http://apparently.me.uk/angularjs-view-specific-sidebars/

Comment: unfortunately I don't have enough knowledge of English to explain better than there